# Enum with start value

Tags: haskell, enums

I need to export some enums from c++ code.
https://github.com/horde3d/Horde3D/blob/master/Horde3D/Bindings/C%2B%2B/Horde3D.h

```
struct H3DGeoRes
{
   enum List
   {
      GeometryElem = 200,
      //...
   };
};

struct H3DAnimRes
{
   enum List
   {
      EntityElem = 300,
      //...
   };
};
```

How I can write this in Haskell? Can I do override fromEnum for type?

```
data H3DGeoRes = GeometryElem | ... deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)
data H3DAnimRes = EntityElem | ... deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

-- not work

instance Enum H3DGeoRes where
  fromEnum x = (fromEnum x) + 200

instance Enum H3DAnimRes where
  fromEnum x = (fromEnum x) + 300
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. The problem is that you'll have to write `fromEnum` by pattern matching, i.e. `fromEnum GeometryElem = 200`. Current code is infinitely recursive. You can manage the boilerplate using Template Haskell extension to generate those instances.

Comment: Thanks, http://codepad.org/JG6tFGWF it work, but I need a lot of enum constants. Perhaps there are ways to shorter

Comment: Take a look at this code. It's quite self-explanatory. As far as I know there's no easier way to do this. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_haskell/Instance_deriving_example

Comment: I guess, you should just declare a separate function. E.g. `geoResNum x = 200 + fromEnum x`.

Comment: I have a function that takes all enum values. h3dGetNodeParamF node H3DGeoRes value and h3dGetNodeParamF node H3DAnimRes value

Comment: h3dGetNodeParamF node (geoResNum H3DGeoRes) value ... it looks bad

Comment: Also, you could use a Peg.js (http://pegjs.majda.cz/online) grammar (http://ideone.com/xCmPxJ) on your code, to get the data structures you need, and then transform them into Haskell code with a little bit of JavaScript (http://ideone.com/wBUbBl). (Edited)

Comment: * http://ideone.com/LRIUNT

Comment: Also,  there's http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html ... but, I'm wondering how to write it in Haskell.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph thanks for your code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem without too much typing is to create a new type class similar to `Enum`. Let's call it `Enumerable`:

`class Enumerable a where
  fromEnumerable :: a -> Int`

You can then write the instance for `Enumerable` using `Enum`:

`instance Enumerable H3DGeoRes where
  fromEnumerable x = fromEnum x + 200`

Whenever using the enumeration of your types `H3DGeoRes` and `H3DAnimRes` you will have to use the functions from the `Enumerable` class and not the `Enum` class. This is a little bit of a nuisance as it will prevent you from using the convenient list syntax for `Enum`.

Comment: This class lacks a context request as `class (Enum a) => Enumerable a where ...` since you use Enum methods.

Comment: @GabrielRiba, the class constraint is not needed unless you were to use the functions from the `Enum` to define default functions in the `Enumerable` class. But perhaps it would be natural to add the constraint anyway.